# how to use selected checkbox value of one jsp in another jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jsp, checkbox

I have one html table row  having dynamic checkboxes with same id in a jsp page and I want to fetch the value  of selected checkboxes from this page  and use it to another jsp page .I'm using `request.getParameter` to fetch the value but I'm getting null in other jsp page.Please suggest me what to do ?

Here is the code where i have dynamic checkbox (index.jsp):

```
<%   for (RecordField recordField : flds) { %>  
<tr>
<td width="15" bgcolor="#46A0F0"><input type="checkbox"  name="tablechkboxl"
id="fieldName"  / ></td>
<td width="200" >
<%= recordField.getFieldName() %> //dynamic fields
<%}                     
 %>
</td></tr>

Now i want to use the selected checboxes value in other jsp as (Submit.jsp):

for (Enumeration e = request.getParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements();){String[]
checkedcolumns = (String) request.getParameterValues("tablechkboxl");
System.out.println("Now i am getting "+checkedcolumns );
}

    But instead of getting name  of checked columns i am getting "on".Anyone please suggest.
```

Comment: post the code what you have tried ?

Comment: why are you giving same id to checkboxes?

Comment: Simply pass the value as query parameter to the second JSP.

Comment: I have updated my question with code .please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selected checkbox has a default value as "on".
So you have to override default value of the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="tablechkboxl" value="<%= recordField.getFieldName() %>"  />
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to your answer to explain what the code is doing and why it solves the OP's problem.  A single line of code is not a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

`on` is the default value. If you want a different value then you need to give the input element a `value="something"` attribute.